# Extracting source from html page

Tags: java

I am trying to read source code from web site using following code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class GrabHTML {

public static void Connect() throws Exception{

 //Set URL
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.ca/");
 URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();

 //Spoof the connection so we look like a web browser
 spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
 String strLine = "";

 //Loop through every line in the source
   while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){

 //Prints each line to the console
   System.out.println(strLine);
  }

 System.out.println("End of page.");
}

public static void main(String[] args){

 try{
  //Calling the Connect method
  Connect();
 }catch(Exception e){

 }
 }
 }
```

But it only reads some part of the source code. When i see the 'View Source' from browser , Google.com has more data.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/ worth mentioning here

Comment: This code works fine for me.  I suspect the User-Agent property doesn't match your browser, and thus the Google site is serving slightly different data in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below statement

> spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
>   5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );